# Group by linq with a long join

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Im trying to make a goup by with a multiple join in this method, but it return me nothing

```
public List<CTarifaAplicada> get_TarifasAplicadas(int id_proforma)
        {
            var pt = (from ta in db.TarifaAplicada
                      where ta.IDProforma == id_proforma
                      join p in db.Proforma on ta.IDProforma equals p.ID
                      join pe in db.PortExpenses on ta.CodigoPE equals pe.CodigoPE
                      join v in db.Voucher on pe.IDVoucher equals v.No
                      select new CTarifaAplicada
                      {
                          CodigoFile = ta.CodigoFile,
                          CodigoPE = ta.CodigoPE,
                          Fecha = ta.Fecha,
                          Id = ta.Id,
                          IDProforma = ta.IDProforma,
                          ITBIS = ta.ITBIS,
                          Monto = ta.Monto,
                          DWT = p.DWT,
                          GRT=p.GRT,
                          LOA=p.LOA,
                          no_Voucher= v.No,
                          voucher=v.Description
                      }).ToList();

            return pt;
```

Im trying to group by v.No , by doing this.

```
Json(cta.get_TarifasAplicadas(id_Proforma).OrderBy(n => n.no_Voucher).GroupBy(n => n.no_Voucher)
```

And this return me nothing. on my grid, Im newbie

Comment: note that your query is just a query with deferred execution, you have to execute it before using the result to bind to your grid. Also your GroupBy result will have no properties, so how could you show that result on your grid?

Comment: `GroupBy` returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. Do you need to see `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>` in your grid? You must project it to appropriate type.

Comment: I want to show this:
                          CodigoFile,
                          CodigoPE,
                          Fecha,
                          Id,
                          IDProforma,
                          ITBIS,
                          Monto,
                          DWT,
                          GRT,
                          LOA,
                          no_Voucher,
                          voucher

but grouped by no_Voucher, I got it on SQL but I dont know how to do it in linq,and I dont want to use a procedure.

Comment: Can you share the grouping SQL query?

Comment: This is my sql group by query::

select v.No,v.Description,SUM(ta.ITBIS) as ITBIS,sum (ta.Monto) as MONTO,p.DWT,p.GRT,p.LOA,ta.Fecha from TarifaAplicada ta
join Proforma p
on p.ID=ta.IDProforma
join PortExpenses pe 
on ta.CodigoPE = pe.CodigoPE
join Voucher v
on v.No = pe.IDVoucher
where ta.IDProforma=33
group by v.No,v.Description,p.DWT,p.GRT,p.LOA,ta.Fecha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your method as (returning `Enumerable` instead of `List` is more sensible):

```
public IEnumerable<CTarifaAplicada> get_TarifasAplicadas(int id_proforma)
{
    var pt = (from ta in db.TarifaAplicada
                where ta.IDProforma == id_proforma
                join p in db.Proforma on ta.IDProforma equals p.ID
                join pe in db.PortExpenses on ta.CodigoPE equals pe.CodigoPE
                join v in db.Voucher on pe.IDVoucher equals v.No
                select new CTarifaAplicada
                    {
                        CodigoFile = ta.CodigoFile,
                        CodigoPE = ta.CodigoPE,
                        Fecha = ta.Fecha,
                        Id = ta.Id,
                        IDProforma = ta.IDProforma,
                        ITBIS = ta.ITBIS,
                        Monto = ta.Monto,
                        DWT = p.DWT,
                        GRT=p.GRT,
                        LOA=p.LOA,
                        no_Voucher= v.No,
                        voucher=v.Description
                    });
    return pt;
}
```

Then group your data and project them as anonymous type as:

```
var groupedData = cta.get_TarifasAplicadas(id_Proforma)
    .GroupBy(n => new {n.no_Voucher, n.voucher, n.DWT, n.GRT, n.LOA, n.Fecha})
    .Select(g => new
                   {
                       g.Key.no_Voucher,
                       g.Key.voucher,
                       ITBIS = g.Sum(r => r.ITBIS),
                       MONTO = g.Sum(r => r.Monto),
                       g.Key.DWT,
                       g.Key.GRT,
                       g.Key.LOA,
                       g.Key.Fecha 
                   });
```

Now you can use `groupedData` to serialize as `JSON` if your lib allows anonymous type serialization. Otherwise, You must define type according to the projected type and use it.